# Cannot return null for non-nullable field Apollo GraphQL

Tags: mongodb, apollo, apollo-client, typegraphql, typegoose

This is my model:

```
export class Task extends BaseModel {
    @Field()
    @prop({ required: true })
    title!: string

    @Field()
    @prop({ required: true })
    index!: number

    @Field(() => User)
    @prop({ required: true, ref: User })
    createdBy!: User

    @Field(() => DateScalar, { nullable: true })
    @prop()
    completedAt?: Date

    @Field({ nullable: true })
    @prop()
    current?: boolean

    @Field(() => Task, { nullable: true })
    @prop({ ref: Task })
    parent?: string

    @Field(() => Boolean, { nullable: true })
    get completed(): boolean {
        const { completedAt } = ((this as any)._doc as Task) || this
        return Boolean(completedAt)
    }
}
```

This is my resolver:

```
@Resolver(() => Task)
export class TaskResolver {

    @Query(() => Task, { nullable: true })
    async task(@Arg('id', () => ID) id: string) {
        return await TaskModel.findById(id).exec()
    }

    @Query(() => Task, { nullable: true})
    async getTaskByTitle(@Arg('title') title: string) {
        return await TaskModel.find({ title: title }).exec()
    }
}
```

When I do a this query I get the error:

```
query GetTaskByTitle($title: String!) {
  getTaskByTitle(title: $title) {
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    title
  }
}
```

When I do this query I get all the correct information:

```
query GetTaskByTitle($taskId: ID!) {
  task(id: $taskId) {
    id
    createdAt
    updatedAt
    title
    index
  }
}
```

The error I am getting specifically is:

```
message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Task.title.",
```

What am I doing wrong in the querying process or the modeling process that is causing this issue?

Comment: Does the title you're looking for exist?

Comment: Yes the title will return properly if I search by the _id but if I search by title it does not show up.

Comment: In the resolver, maybe `TaskModel.find` doesn't return what you expect. try `TaskModel.findOne` or something similiar. Check this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findOne